# After writing, the file is not modified on Windows Phone 8.0

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

During the execution of this script it is not detected any error, but the file isn't modified. **Reading works, writing strangely not.**

My script for writing:

```
private void firstLaunch(){
    try { 
        StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter("Path/something.txt");
        outfile.WriteLine("somethingElse");
        outfile.Close();
    }
    catch (IOException ex){
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

The file already exists and has already been included in the project with visual studio. At the moment it is completely empty.

Could you help me?

Comment: How are you verifying that nothing has been written? Maybe StreamWriter creates another file (in different dictionary). You can use https://isostorespy.codeplex.com/ to check phone's or emulator's internal storage.

Comment: This was my only doubt! I'm just checking the file modification in the project folder, but the file is changed only within the emulator, can be?

Comment: That is probably it. Your file gets copied into the emulator, where you write line to it. But in your VS solution, you have the original and unchanged file.

Comment: You're right, the problem is that I can not verify this in any way, even with         [isostorespy](https://isostorespy.codeplex.com/) because is a text file :(  I try to do a reading.

Comment: Why not? You can open the file from IsoSpy in Notepad for example.

Comment: Why the folders of IsoSpy are not the same of my project?

Comment: Well, when you deploy an app, it is note like the VS solution folders structure is copied to the emulator/phone. However I don't know what exactly gets copied and what does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
var res = App.GetResourceStream(new Uri("test.txt", UriKind.Relative));
var txt = new StreamReader(res.Stream).ReadToEnd();
```

Just make sure that the file has the Build Action set to Content.
If the file is empty, I would recommend creating one in the folder of your app using IsolatedStorage. That way you can check with IsoStoreSpy the contents of your file.